# rviz is agonizingly slow

Tags: kinect, rviz, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Are there any common reasons that would cause RVIZ to update very very slowly? I've been working with the Xbox Kinect and depth point clouds and every time I start rviz with the openni_camera node (ie, `$roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch, $rosrun rviz rviz`   as suggested from the http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera guide), everything on Ubuntu slows way down. The point cloud updates maybe once every 30 seconds. Is it just a problem of the amount of data being passed from the Kinect to rviz? Or could it be that my Asus EeeBox PC doesn't have enough umph to handle the data? Or is there some mysterious setting on rviz that only the enlightened know about which makes rviz more useful as a real-time observation tool for what your robot is up to?

I've run through the rviz documentation and aside from changing a few settings using the `dynamic_reconfigure` gui I can't find any solutions. Advice, anyone? Do any of you pro ROS users have optimal system setting suggestions?

Thanks,

Khiya

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10442/rviz-is-agonizingly-slow/) by [Khiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/669/khiya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2011-06-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The magic trick (*particularly* when dealing with Kinect point clouds) is to have serious hardware-accelerated 3D graphics. If you're doing 3D rendering in software, it will be agonizingly slow, no matter what.

Put a different way: a single Kinect pointcloud message is on the order of 10MB. Multiply that by 30fps, and you're putting serious, serious load on your system, even before you have to visualize it.

The [PCL OpenNI wrappers and visualization tools](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/openni_grabber.php#openni-grabber) might get you better results (although that's outside of ROS proper), but the sheer datarate problem isn't going away.

If you're willing to handle the clouds at a lower framerate (not that this will solve your visualization problem), take a look at [Topic Tools](http://www.ros.org/wiki/topic_tools), particularly the `throttle` node.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-06-29**:
The EeeBox's graphic card is just an integrated intel processor.  It's not going to be able to keep up with the number of points the kinect sends out.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What graphics card does the Asus have? If you have a lower-end Intel integrated graphics card, you may not be able to do much. However, if you have ATI or nVidia card, try installing the restricted drivers.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-06-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-07-13**:
In your menu: System->Administration->Hardware Drivers

**Comment by [ringo42](https://answers.ros.org/users/651/ringo42/) on 2011-07-02**:
I have an ATI Mobility Radeon X1400, can you tell me how to install the restricted drivers? I have the same slowness issue with the kinnect